# Ember Binding jQuery .val

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

```
{{input value=inputValue}}
$("input").val("Test");
```

The jQuery command does not trigger Ember to update the value. I tried `.trigger('change')` it did not work either.

EDIT: I have a table on a page. The table is created using a third part component (I can't change it). I want Ember to know when the user clicks on a row. I created a hidden text field. Whenever the user selects a row, the value of the hidden text field is set to the contents of the row using `jQuery.val()`. The problem is that Ember is not recognizing the change. If I make the textbox visible, select a row, and then just click anywhere in the textbox, Ember recognizes the change. So `jQuery.val()` is not triggering Ember to update the bound value.

Comment: You shouldn't set the value with jQuery generally, what's your use case?

Comment: My use case: simulating user input in component and integration (capybara) tests.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
this.$('#table').on("click", function() {
  var selected = this.$('#table tr.selected')[0];
  var text = selected.innerText.split("\t");
  this.$(this.get('columns')).each(function(i) {
    var column = this.get('columns')[i];
    this.set(column.title, text[i]);
  });
});
```

Comment: Please make sure to explain how your code solves OPs problem

Answer (score 1):

You should set the value through `this.set('inputValue', 'Enter new value')` from the component/controller for the change to take effect

Comment: I can't. I am binding data to a hidden field. jQuery is setting the field depending on user actions. But Ember doesn't update the value when you use jQuery .val().

Comment: You should give more information/code for people to be able to help you out. changing the value from ember, will not trigger the two way binding. You can create a hidden field like this `{{ input type="hidden" valueBinding=newValue }}`. If you're using custom jquery actions, then something like this with a listener: `var _this = this;

this.$('input').on('change', function(e) { _this.set('inputValue', newValue) })`